# glBlendFunc transparency in cocos2d?

Tags: opengl, cocos2d, c

GL_ONE, GL_ONE

This makes the flamingoes transparent on:

http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php

but not in cocos2d using:

sprite.blendFunc = (ccBlendFunc){GL_ONE, GL_ONE}

How can I achieve a similar effect in cocos2d?

Thank you.

Comment: What does it actually do in cocos2d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the sprite.blendFunc will be ignored if the sprite is part of spritesheet or atlas or whatever else has blendFunc